# Why does OSPF use flooding despite using multicast?

Tags: routing, router, ospf, layer3, multicast

We know that flooding is only possible in layer2 switch. But in OSPF router in layer3 uses flooding with multicasting. Suppose we have one router in OSPF uses multicast address 225.0.0.9. If router sends a message, every router get the message  belongs to same group using class D address 225.0.0.9. But my questions are

A) If I using multicast address so why flooding is necessary because by multicasting everyone get message?

B) If I use unicast instead of multicast what's problem will be happen ?

Comment: We have had a [long discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129638/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-effenok) on this topic.  I recommend that you try to answer your own question to make sure you understand everything.

Comment: See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/45095/8499).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76265/29837, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69301369/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why OSPF uses flooding instead of using multicast?

Those are two very different concepts. OSPF on a broadcast network uses multicast to exchange routes. It floods by telling ever other OSPF router to which it is connected in the same area about all the routes it knows.

> We know that flooding is only possible in layer2 switch.

That is a completely different thing than OSPF flooding. The word is the same, but it is a very different meaning.

> Suppose we have one router in OSPF uses multicast address 225.0.0.9.

That would not work. That multicast group is used by RIPv2, not OSPF.

> If router sends a message, every router get the message belongs to
> same group using class D address 225.0.0.9.

No, because an OSPF router does not listen to that multicast group, and the multicast packets will be dropped at the interface.

> If I using multicast address so why flooding is necessary because by
> multicasting everyone get message?

You are confusing the flooding term. An OSPF router can have neighbors on multiple interfaces. The OSPF flooding term means it tell all its connected OSPF neighbors in the same area about the routes it has. OSPF on a broadcast network does use multicast, but it is a link-local multicast that cannot be sent to a different network. The OSPF router needs to send routes to all the OSPF routers in its area that are connected to all its interfaces that are participating in the OSPF process. Some of the interfaces may be using a broadcast medium, and some may be using a non-broadcast medium where multicast is not supported.

> If I use unicast instead of multicast what's problem will be happen ?

You need to understand the differences between OSPF on a broadcast medium (elects DR and BDR and uses multicast) and on a non-broadcast medium (must have neighbor addresses configured and exchange routes with each neighbor individually).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129667/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-why-does-ospf-use-flooding-despite-using-mult).

Comment: could define two terms "link-local multicast" and "broadcast network".

Comment: Link-local multicast means it cannot leave the link on which it originated. You need to learn to look up stuff on RFCs. [RFC 5771](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771.html#section-4) explains different multicast ranges for IPv4. For example: "_4. Local Network Control Block (224.0.0/24) Addresses in the Local Network Control Block are used for protocol control traffic that is not forwarded off link.  Examples of this type of use include OSPFIGP All Routers (224.0.0.5) [RFC2328]._"

Comment: [RFC 2328](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2328) defines what OSPF means for broadcast networks: "_Networks supporting many (more than two) attached routers, together with the capability to address a single physical message to all of the attached routers (broadcast)._"

Comment: your statement "OSPF on a broadcast network uses multicast to exchange routes. " means OSPF never use broadcasting, always use multicast? OSPF can use all of multicast , unicast, broadcast depends upon configuration?

Comment: OSPF does not use broadcast; on a broadcast network, it defaults to multicast, electing DR and BDR, but it could be configured to use unicast on a broadcast network, but that requires configuring each neighbor router individually, and that means more traffic than necessary.

Comment: When OSPF uses broadcasting? And why unicast causes more traffic than necessary in broadcast network ?

Comment: OSPF does not broadcast. Using unicast on a broadcast network means that every router must send to every other neighbor. You can have a lot of  OSPF connections between neighbors where traffic is passing on the network. With multicast, each router only has a connection to the DR and BDR, and the DR will multicast once for everything it receives from the other routers and all the other routers can get the information from the single multicast, rather than needing to pass it to each neighbor individually.

Comment: DVR uses unicast or multicast or broadcast? They only communicate with neighbor only?

Comment: That depends on the protocol. For example, RIPv1 uses broadcast, but RIPv2 uses multicast.

Comment: Actually 225.0.0.9 is not used by RIPv2. The address used is link local multicast 224.0.0.9

Comment: @RonMaupin one thing tell like link state(ospf) routing protocol, DVR protocol also exchange the information between router which running DVR only, and in between two DVR routers there   also exists non-DVR router which not running DVR, and non-DVR router just routes information packet by which another DVR router get that information? Am I correct?

Comment: @RonMaupin like link state(ospf) routing protocol, two DVR routers not necessarily adjacent? In between two DVR router more than non-DVR router could also exists? Am I correct?

Comment: If you mean RIP, then a non-RIP router between them woul not let them be neighbors. The original RIP used broadcasts that cannot be sent across a router, and RIPv2 uses link-local multicast that cannot be routed. Basically, for IGP routers, they need to be directly connected on the same network

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever we talk about OSPF, flooding means "send the data the any router learned form one neighbor to all other adjacent routers. "

Actually flooding means a little more then that. Flooding is an algorithm to forward packet **through a network** which works by having **each network node on the path** send a packet received from one neighbor to all other neighbors.

> First I need to understand multicasting little bit. Before entering into main answer. One class D address use as multicast address and treated as one group. For example , a institution may have an internal video system that sends multicast video streams. The video application on a host would be configured to subscribe to a "channel" on a particular multicast group through by neighbor routers. Whenever channel sends any video the then all group members get it know.

This is correct. Multicast however is used to describe that a network is capable of doing it, it does not specify how a network does it. IP multicast (or at least approaches that I know) does rely on network having calculated routes. Thus OSPF, a protocol that calculates these routes, cannot use that kind of multicast.

> Same thing is happening here in OSPF routers using multicast. When any OSPF router using multicast address then it's all neighbor router treated as multicast group restricted by one hop distance and flooding needed to deliver information to whole network.

I would say that OSPF router uses multicast address. This multicast address is link-local. In this case multicast will be done by layer 2, not layer 3. This IP multicast address maps to layer 2 multicast address. On multipoint links (e.g., Ethernet) routers will use layer 2 multicast capabilities to deliver packets to all other routers on this link. I would abstract from this case before you understand the basics.

> When an OSPF router receives a multicast packet, it does not forward the packet. That is what we mean by one hop.

well, this is kinda not the case. OSPF floods so called LSAs (link state advertisements). These packets are forwarded. In a sense there is an outer OSPF header that is used hop by hop. A router receives a packet, processes outer header, then creates a new packet with a new outer header, where it puts the original LSA. Then it forwards the packet.

> The router does not forward the same packet it receives. The router puts the information into its table and then sends a new packet with its new information to its neighbors.

this is what distance-vector algorithm does. OSPF routers do not modify LSAs they forward.

> So the information (LSP) gets flooded, using a new multicast packet at each hop.This addreses my **first** question.

well, yes

> Now coming to **second** question, if OSPF uses unicast then any router have to discover each of it's neighbors and keep track of them. It's harder to do with unicast. So multicasting is using here.

OSPF router needs to discover each of it's neighbors and keep track of them. It uses this information to construct an LSA. This is done by HELLO packets. These packets are not flooded.

However, OSPF does use multicast addresses. You can assume that this is done for convenience and doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129666/discussion-on-answer-by-alok-maity-why-does-ospf-use-flooding-despite-using-mult).

Comment: "_Actually flooding means a little more then that. Flooding is an algorithm to forward packet through a network which works by having each router on the path send a packet received from one neighbor to all other neighbors._" No. Routers do not flood packets. Routing protocols flood routing information. You keep confusing the flooding term with the way switches flood.

Comment: "_IP multicast (or at least approaches that I know) does rely on network having calculated routes. Thus OSPF, a protocol that calculates these routes, cannot use that kind of multicast._" That is completely wrong. IP multicast is simply sending to an IP multicast group address. OSPF can multicast on a broadcast medium.

Comment: "_I would say that OSPF router uses multicast address, it does not use multicast._" That makes no sense. Sending to a multicast group is using multicast.

Comment: "_When an OSPF router receives a multicast packet, it does not forward the packet. That is what we mean by one hop." "well, this is kinda not the case._" Yes, that is the case. The link-local multicast cannot be forwarded, so it is a single hop.

Comment: "_A router receives a packet, processes outer header, then creates a new packet with a new outer header, where it puts the original LSA. Then it forwards the packet._" You are confusing the router and the routing protocol. Routing protocols do not route, and the router only forwards a routing protocol packet to the routing protocol process, not beyond the router. It is up to the routing protocol process to decide if it will advertise routing information to another interface.

Comment: "_So the information (LSP) gets flooded, using a new multicast packet at each hop.This addreses my first question._" Only if OSPF is sending on a broadcast medium. If OSPF is running on multiple interfaces, and some are non-broadcast media, the traffic received via multicast from a broadcast medium would be sent via unicast on the non-broadcast media.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, that's what I learned from Ron trunk,effenok

Comment: @RonMaupin flooding is an algorithm that works exactly like it is described. it can be applied at layer 2, layer 3, or layer 7 (e.g., unstructured peer-to-peer overlays). OSPF uses this algorithm to flood routing information.

Comment: "_if OSPF uses unicast then any router have to discover each of it's neighbors and keep track of them. It's harder to do with unicast. So multicasting is using here._" No, you are confusing things again. OSPF must be configured for neighbors using unicast.

Comment: @effenok, the router does not flood received packets. The routing protocol may create packets and send them on, but the router does not flood, the routing protocol process may flood.

Comment: no, IP multicast is a layer 3 multicast. there is such thing and there are protocols. The fact that there is noone using them does not change this.

Comment: @RonMaupin "the router does not flood received packets." , no, the correct statement is "no existing routing protocol floods user traffic". they can do it, it is just unfeasible.

Comment: where is that "move discussion in chat button"

Comment: The routing protocol _does not route_, it only exchanges routing information. Routers rout based on the routing table, and a routing protocol _may_ populate the routing table if its routes are the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129669/discussion-between-effenok-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: @Ron trunk please join chat..

Comment: @RonMaupin like ospf, DVR also application layer protocol?

Comment: Routing protocols are applications to exchange routing information.. It does not matter if it is an EGP or IGP, nor if the IGP is DV or LS. Routers can route just fine without using a routing protocol to exchange routing information with other routers, but that does not scale well and requires manual intervention to change routing information, so it is static. Routing protocols are dynamic, automatically communicating routing information when changes happen.

Comment: @RonMaupin could I say DVR is application layer Routing protocols and it's routing is performing in at layer 3?

Comment: Remember that _routing protocols do not route_. Routers route packets at layer-3 based on their routing tables. Routing protocols are applications, and they are only one of three ways (and the lowest priority way) to populate the routing table, but they really have nothing to do with packet routing.

Comment: @RonMaupin routing protocol populate the routing table at application layer or layer3?

Comment: The routing protocols gather routing information as an application. A router may or may not use that information to populate its routing table. The router does not use networking to perform internal functions like populating its routing table. For example, if I configure a router's routing table through the router's command line, what layer is that? It is not going through the network stack layers.

Comment: @RonMaupin routing protocol exists in application layer but routing table  but exists in layer 3   but flooding is doing at application layer, it's not understanding?

Comment: Routers have a process to update the routing table from the various sources (directly connected networks, statically configured networks, and routing protocol information, in that order), and it chooses the best routes from all sources to install in the routing table, not installing any but the best, but it is not using the network to process the routes, so it is not in a network layer.

Comment: A routing protocol maintains a database, and it updates the database with information from databases in other routers. That is an application. The host (router) may or may not use information in the database for its own purposes (populating the routing table). The routing protocol does note route, nor does it directly update the routing table.. It only exchanges its routing information with other routing protocol databases.

Comment: @RonMaupin routing protocol information means routing table which exists in application layer and routing table for packet switching exists in layer 3?

Comment: The routing protocol does not change the routing table, that is up to the router. A routing protocol only updates its database, from which the router may or may not use to populate its routing table.

Comment: @RonMaupin that means routing protocol at application layer maintain routing database and router maintain routing table at layer3?

Comment: The router maintains the routing table, but it is not at a network layer. It routes packets using layer-3 addresses. A PC updates its screen, but at what network layer? No network layer, it is a function of the OS, but it is not using the network stack, so there is no network layer involved. A router OS has a function to update the routing table, but it does not go through a network stack to do that, so there is no network layer for the internal router process.

Comment: @RonMaupin by routing protocol information (database) at application layer and router has routing table at layer 3 . So by application layer data , router should not update it's routing table at layer3?is it correct?

Comment: Again, the function of updating the routing table is not using the network stack. You cannot assign a layer of the network stack to something that does not use the network stack. Packets passing through the router are routed at layer-3.

Comment: Processes inside a host (PC, router, server, printer ,etc.) use IPC (Inter-Process Communication) provided by the host OS (routers have a host OS). IPC does not use the network stack layers, so IPC is not assigned to a network layer. If you are pressed to do that, it would be the application layer, but it does not travel down the network stack to other network layers. It is really not appropriate to try to assign it to a network layer.

Comment: @RonMaupin that's understood. But my question is that routing protocol information(database) exchange  with another router at application layer which running on routing protocol information using network stack? But routing is happening at layer3 by router by routing table?

Comment: @RonMaupin database at application layer for routing information protocol and routing table both different?

Comment: Yes, routing of packets takes the packet up through layer-3, stripping off the layer-2 frame, inspecting the layer-3 destination address, and forwarding to the next interface based on the layer-3 address compared to routing table entries. Updating of the routing table is done by router processes that have nothing to do with the actual routing of the packets..

Comment: Each routing protocol maintains its own database (somtimes more than one table per routing protocol). You can run multiple routing protocols, and for some, multiple instances of a routing protocol, all on the same router. Each routing protocol and/or routing protocol instance maintains its own tables. The router can draw on all of them to update its routing table.

Comment: @RonMaupin  by routing protocol database how routing table is updated? Routing table is for routing purpose and routing protocol database for another router which running routing protocol database? My question is why needed routing table to be updated by routing protocol database? Both are totally different things.

Comment: A router has a process that looks for changes to directly connected networks, static route configurations, and routing protocol changes. When a change is detected to any of those, it will look to see if the routing table must be updated. If so, it will pick the best route to a destination from any of the sources with that route. Absent any special configurations, in order: directly connected, statically configured, then routing protocols  See the [Cisco AD table](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/15986-admin-distance.html#topic2).

Comment: @RonMaupin by routing protocol information, routing table changes, is it router internal process,by Not populate the routing table? Am I correct?

Comment: The process that updates the routing table uses IPC to communicate with other processes, e.g. a routing protocol, to gather information necessary to update the routing table. The process that actually routes packets simply looks at the resulting routing table to determine the path to forward packets. It does not need to see how the sausage is made (how the routing table is created/updated) to eat the sausage (use the routing table information to determine the path).

Comment: @RonMaupin in DVR we read in the book the exchange the routing table, they are actually exchanging routing protocol information among the router?

Comment: The old, original RIP did something like that, but we now have faster processors, multiprocessing and more memory, so modern routing protocols have separated things. You will still find old, obsolete information like that around. For example, most network classes still require learning about network address classes that have been obsolete since 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet).

Comment: @RonMaupin once again your great help. It's impossible to say thank you adequately.

Comment: @RonMaupin The old, original RIP exchange routing table with another router between layer3? I mean one router's routing table exchange with different router which is updated by routing protocol information or not updated  by routing protocol information ?

Comment: It is still an application exchanging data. but the application would update the routing table. There is more to it than that, even for the old RIP because it used UDP as the transport protocol (above layer-3), and it had to process and make sure that the received information was valid for the routing table, e.g. not install an external route for a directly connected network. There is also split horizon and poison reverse it had to take into account. RIP was still an application, but it just sent everything (except for split horizon).

Comment: @RonMaupin one thing I don't understand the difference between old RIP and nowadays Rip?both are exchanging application database..

Comment: RIPv1 used broadcast UDP datagrams, and it had limitations, such as slow updates causing convergence problems classful networks, etc. RIPv2 uses multicast UDP datagrams, can use CIDR, sends triggered updates, etc. There are many under-the-hood changes, too. RIPng is updated for IPv6. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-ripv1-and-ripv2/

Comment: @RonMaupin in application exchanging data which contains routing protocol information which contains IP address information also?

Comment: The IP address information is the advertised networks. Routing tables have destination network information: the network address and mask. That is the data stored in the routing table. Various routing protocols may also have other information (OSPF has multiple tables of things like source router, area, etc.). RIP is pretty basic.

Comment: @RonMaupin dvr, ospf doesn't contain IP address and subnet masks  in their application data?

Comment: @RonMaupin I am asking this question because ripv1 doesn't contains mask in exchange data because their subnet mask is same but in ripv2 may have different subnet masks in exchange data, so ripv2 need to exchange with other router.That's why I am asking dvr, ospf doesn't contain IP address and subnet masks in their application data for ripv1 and contain for ripv2?

Comment: Right. Modern routing protocols include the network masks because we no longer have network address classes (even if schools and exams still require you to learn them).

Comment: @RonMaupin I have one question on later2, in wireless where csma/ca is used, nowadays is it full-duplex or still half duplex?

Comment: Hubs are basically extinct because they only do 10/100. It is possible to configure switch interfaces for half duplex up to 1 Gbps, but that is not a good idea because you would need to configure the connecting device the same way. Everything at 1 Gbps defaults to full duplex, and all above 1 Gbps are only full duplex.

Comment: Wi-Fi is a shared medium, so it must use CSMA/CA.

Comment: @RonMaupin "Wi-Fi is a shared medium, so it must use CSMA/CA."--- means full duplex?

Comment: No, half duplex. Carrier Sense Multiple Access/ Collision Avoidance. That means a shared medium, and that means it is half duplex because you cannot both send and receive at the same time. The receiver would burn out if it was receiving while you send on the same frequency in the same box. The signal would be too strong.

Comment: @RonMaupin when receiver received signal it's almost attenuated, so why signal would be too strong when send?

Comment: I'm talking about the recover in the same device that is sending. It must be off, else it will burn out from the sent signal on the same antenna. The is no attenuation.

Answer (score 0):

"Flooding" means LSA is sent to all routers in the area (not just the given network), whereas multicasting means the OSPF pkt (with LSA in it) is listened to by all OSPF routers on the given network (not the the whole area).

Unicasting would require more packets, so it would be less efficient. (224.0.0.9 is for RIPv2 BTW, not OSPF; "all OSPF routers" is 224.0.0.5, the acks will be to 224.0.0.6, BDRs and DRs)

Comment: how exactly do you understand network here? And the part about 224.0.0.6 is actually incorrect. It is more complicated than use one addr for LSAs and one addr for ACKs.